# Knime Sumifs based on date range

Tags: sumifs, knime

I’m somewhat new to Knime and have hit a wall. I’m trying to use Knime to do what I can do in Excel. I want to calculate SUMIFS based on multiple criteria.

Criteria to use:
Customer #
Product Code

I want to calculate trailing 30 day stockouts based on Customer/Product/Date.

I’ve looked at multiple examples of group by, column aggregator or loops and I can’t seem to figure this out.

I’ve attached an example of the data as well as the desired outcome. [Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpBEH.png)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out:
Nodes Used: Chunk Loop -> Table Row to Variable -> Rule based row filter -> Group By -> Column Appender -> Loop end

Rule Based row filter is where the Criteria of the Sumif goes
Group By is where the aggregations of what to Sumif goes.